# Entity Framework - filtering and retrieving child entities on child entity condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

My problem is as follows: I have a `Product` entity which looks like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public string Excerpt { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
public DateTime Published { get; set; }
public string[] Tags { get; set; }
public int PublisherId { get; set; }
public virtual User Publisher { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<MyImage> Images { get; set; }
```

Now this `Product` entity can have many `Images` (as a child entity) which looks as follows:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
public bool IsMain { get; set; }
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

So, I've got a controller route, where I would like to retrieve all the products and only those images, which are main product images (most of the time, it's going to be only a single image, but I still prefer to return a list of them).

Currently, what I am trying to do, does not work:

```
public async Task<PagedList<Product>> GetProducts(UserParams userParams)
{
     var productsFromRepo = context.Products
         .Select(p => new {
             Product = p,
             Images = p.Images.Where(i => i.IsMain)
         })
         .OrderByDescending(b => b.Product.Published);

     var productsToReturn = productsFromRepo.Select(i => i.Product).AsQueryable();
     return await PagedList<Product>.CreateAsync(productsToReturn, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

I try to get all products, and their main image. And return a product with it's main image, and not all images. As you can see, I am returning a `PagedList` object, where I need to pass an `IQueryable` as first parameter of `CreateAsync` method.

The thing is, I managed to do the filtering on my anonymously projected object (`productsFromRepo`). But I can not figure out how to return that anonymous object as product object with filtered Images list.

It's always returning all images, not filtered how I need.

In this problem, I must have my lastly projected object, in this case `productsToReturn` to be an `IQueryable` object.

In my project, I am using lazy loading. So all child entities are lazy loaded by default.

So basically, what I get **now** is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "My First Product",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
        "category": "Uncategorized",
        "price": 15.0,
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum",
        "tags": [
            "Tag1",
            "Tag2"
        ],
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "test",
                "isMain": true,
                "dateAdded": "2020-07-15T22:40:09.285481",
                "image":"/9j/...."
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "description": "test1",
                "isMain": false,
                "dateAdded": "2020-07-15T23:15:44.74166",
                "image":"/9j/...."
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "description": "test1",
                "isMain": false,
                "dateAdded": "2020-07-15T23:27:39.636685",
                "image":"/9j/...."
            }
        ],
        "published": "2020-07-15T22:39:27.89482",
        "publisher": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": null,
            "lastName": null,
            "email": "testemail@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

And what i **need** is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "My First Product",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
        "category": "Uncategorized",
        "price": 15.0,
        "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum",
        "tags": [
            "Tag1",
            "Tag2"
        ],
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "test",
                "isMain": true,
                "dateAdded": "2020-07-15T22:40:09.285481",
                "image":"/9j/...."
            },
        ],
        "published": "2020-07-15T22:39:27.89482",
        "publisher": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": null,
            "lastName": null,
            "email": "testemail@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Entities reflect data state, and only data state. If you want filtered results for your view that is a separate concern. *Don't* send Entities to the view, *Do* send ViewModels to the view. A ViewModel will represent the data your view needs, and only the data your view needs, the way your view expects. Entities expose too much about your domain model and leave you wide open to unexpected performance issues and tampering if server code is sloppy.

Comment: @StevePy This is not my controller method you're seeing. It's repository method. I am not returning plain entities, i am returning a DTO, where I pick neccessary data for that controller to return. So thank you for noticing, but the question is not about that entirely.

Comment: `var productsToReturn = productsFromRepo.Select(i => i.Product)` reflects a Product Entity. To return a DTO, you should use `Select` to project to a DTO using the Product and the "main" images. I.e. `productsFromRepo.Select(i => new ProductDTO { ProductId = i.Product.ProductId, /* etc */ Images = i.Images.Select(x => new ImageDTO { /* translate desired image properties to DTO */ }).ToList() })` Compose a Product DTO with details from the product, and populating images from the filtered results rather than returning the Product entity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting on products, try selecting on the images:

```
public async Task<PagedList<Product>> GetProducts(UserParams userParams)
{
     var productsFromRepo = context.Images
         .Where(i => i.IsMain)
         .Select(i => new Product {
             Id = i.Product.Id,
             Title = i.Product.Title,
             ...
             Images = new List<Image>{ i }
         })
         .OrderByDescending(b => b.Published)
         .AsQuerable();

     return await PagedList<Product>.CreateAsync(productsFromRepo, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is if my product does not have an image at all, it will not be in the list. Thus, i need all products with or without main images, only if they have one or more image, only to return the main one. Thank you for your answer, it's almost what i need.

Comment: That's a good point. Have you considered rather than having the IsMain property on Image, have a foreign key in Product which points to the main image directly separate to the collection of images? Then you could just Select on the Main image - if there is one - and not load the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the anonymous object doesn't help in my opinion. You can either filter the product's pictures *after* you retrieve it from the database, or use **Query Filter** if you want to stop EF from bringing it from the database.

Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to get a clear picture.

The idea is that you include the query filter in the fluent api configuration of the pictures entity:

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsMain);
```

This will stop EF from retrieving the pictures that aren't set as main, *in ALL cases by default*. If you want EF to retrieve all pictures (i.e. in pictures index) you have to use

```
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
```

in your query.

P.S. I didn't include the full code snippets, if it doesn't make sense to you, ask me to demonstrate the full code.